# redefinition of module 'CSQLite' when i build SQLite.swift

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

```
platform :ios, ’10.1’
target 'SwiftDemo' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0.0-beta2'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
pod 'MJRefresh', '~> 3.1.12'
pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.3'
end
```

this is my podfile, and after i put SQLite.swift into my project, there is a error like my title

Answer (score -1):

1) Run pod install --repo-update.

2) Re-open the workspace

Comment: i'm sure sqlite.swift is latest, and re-open does not help me,thx